# How do I make my objects path identical on every device?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, skaction

My problem is that I don't know how to make my objects path identical on all the devices (iPhones + iPads).

My goal is to make my object move close to the screen-edge and all the way around. I figured how to make it work on a specific resolution by using CGPointMake and then using SKAction.sequence, but really can't figure how to make it do the same for every device without changing the CGPoints.

Hope someone is able to help me!

Comment: Come up with a scaling rule that you apply to your points so they work on all resolutions. However sometimes you can't just upscale the positions because the aspect ratios of the devices are too different. If this is the case then you will have to break your scaling into sub-cases.

Comment: Yeah, I guess scaling can cause some problems with (fx) iPhone 6. Can I somehow tell  the scene to act as if it's an specific size always, so I wouldn't have to scale?

Comment: This might not be the best choice, but I managed to make it work on the different devices by setting some if-statements.

if frame.height == 480 {

// then the CGPoints for this size

}

and then the same goes for all the other device-sizes.